# Is it correct to assert that pure RESTful applications require HTTPS to be secure?

Tags: security, rest

Given the fact that for pure REST each resource request from the client carries authentication information, it appears to me that the only way to secure against replay or copy-and-paste attacks requires that the REST request runs inside an HTTPS protected channel.

Is that assertion correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

False. The fact that each request carries authentication does **not** mean that a request can be replayed. HTTP [DIGEST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) can be used for authentication and a digest authentication *cannot* be replayed, because the challenge from the server will carry a different nonce on each connection and clients cannot reuse a nonce:

> - Server nonce is allowed to contain timestamps. Therefore the server may
>     inspect nonce attributes submitted by
>     clients, to prevent replay attacks.
> - Server is also allowed to maintain a list of recently issued or used server
>     nonce values to prevent reuse

Requiring HTTPS is not bad on itself, it certainly adds increased privacy and tampering protection for the traffic, but it is not *required* to prevent replay and copy-paste attacks.

Comment: I don't get how HTTP DIGEST authentication would protect against Man-in-the-middle replay attacks or server spoofing. Can you expand how these attack vectors are addressed with HTTP DIGEST?

Comment: Man-in-the-middle is not replay nor copy-paste. To protect against MITM one needs positive proof of the party it connect too, and only SSL can give that out-of-the-box by means of name validation and certificate trust chain. So you're right in that MITM attacks cannot be prevented by DIGEST. But MITM is a much more sophisticated attack than replay, it requires the attacker to have control of your infrastructure (eg. DNS) so you connect to the MITM instead of the target to start with. As I said, HTTPS/SSL are not bad, they always help, but don't simply dismiss simple authentication.

Comment: HTTP Digest has a nonce that prevents replay attacks, because your response (in the client's request) needs to use it and the server can choose to accept a nonce only once. What HTTP Digest doesn't protect against (when used in plain HTTP) is tampering with the request's entity.

Comment: Good stuff, Remus/Bruno, thank you for these insights. I was kinda stuck mentally and this exchange has opened up the brain again. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The assertion itself is incorrect since it lacks context. REST is an architectural style. Although HTTP is the typical example of supporting protocol for a RESTful system, the security of such a system would depend on a number of factors.

First of all, there are HTTP authentication mechanisms that are orthogonal to the application running on top of HTTP, e.g. HTTP Basic and HTTP Digest. While HTTP Basic isn't secure, there are mechanisms that can help protect against replay attacks in HTTP Digest, which doesn't send the authentication information in clear either. (There can be and there are other authentication mechanisms that are orthogonal to the application and that can be more secure than HTTP Digest too.)

There are also specifications for securing HTTP requests at the message level (e.g. [HTTPsec](http://httpsec.org)).

However, the wide availability of SSL/TLS stacks on various languages/platforms/OS makes it rather convenient for many applications to protect the communication between the client and the server via HTTPS.
Not using HTTPS doesn't mean that your system is going to be insecure (although it might require a bit of work to protect the data); and using HTTPS isn't a guarantee that your application will be secure either. Security is a broad topic and you need to consider the range of threats you want to be protected against before making an evaluation.

Comment: The context is replay attacks in its many forms. To be more informative: I want to build a RESTful public service API for customer recommendations. Customers will accumulate and update information (content) in their account and the service will adapt the recommendations based on that content. This implies that the API needs to be solid in protecting a customer's privacy and security.

Comment: @Ravenwater HTTPS is definitely a good way to achieve some of your goals, but it's about securing the communication channel between the client and the server. On top of this, you could have a variety of authentication mechanisms, ranging from HTTP Basic to more complex/custom SAML-based things for example; it depends on what you have/need. Depending on what your typical client is going to be (a browser perhaps), it's worth looking into the website security advice regarding CSRF, XSS, ... (The idea of a token like it's used to protect against CSRF may be useful to prevent replay attacks too.)

Comment: Well, HTTPSec could work and do message-level encryption (so could other variants, say S-HTTP), but considering what libraries are most commonly available, HTTPS is probably the easiest.

Comment: Regarding SAML, the "RESTfulness" of the standard [SAML bindings](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf) is arguable. However, you could have your own authentication headers that pass SAML messages, if you control client and server.